# Loop count in video clip settings, how to apply changes to composition?

Tags: after-effects

I created a grid of about 50 videos. I want them all to loop so I changed the loop count of the videos via `Interpret Footage > Main... > Loop`. The changes show up in the timeline, but they are not applied. When I let it preview it, the videos only run once.

I don't want to add those 50 clips again to the composition and apply the transforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your videos are of different durations. If no, just precompose the grid layers and loop that composition. If yes, worst case scenario is to precompose each video layer and loop those.

Comment: Yes, different durations. And I already added the videos to the composition thinking it would be easy to loop them later on. But now I set them all to loop, but when I render it, they only run once, then go to black. Although their new durations are shown in the timeline.

Comment: Does the extended duration look fully opaque or semi-transparent?

Comment: The normal duration is full color, and the extended duration is semi-transparent I think. There is a border at least, not sure if it's semi-transparent inside.

Comment: All you need to do is extend the tail-end of the normal duration. That's the only part trimmed for display in the composition.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Find out after a while.